# Can we develope User Script in Opera Mobile using Opera Widget?

Tags: mobile, widget, opera

Is it possible to develop an addon/plugin in opera mobile like greasemonkey which will load users script when a web page is loaded every time?

Comment: Desktop opera has it built in. Try looking in similiar places (I can't help more, last Opera mobile I used was v4)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can go to opera:config#User%20JavaScript in your Opera Mobile. If this address works and the setting exists, you have User JavaScript support and should be able to write any scripts you want by pointing the "User JavaScript File" setting to a suitable file or folder on your phone's file system.

(If the setting isn't there I'm afraid you're out of luck - for now - I have no idea what versions of Opera Mobile support User JS..)

Comment: Check for example this link for information on how to install user scripts: http://userjs.org/help/installation , adapt instructions to a mobile file system somehow :)

Comment: Opera Mobile 11 has User Javascript option in the "User Prefs" section of about:config.